# Micronaut Introspection does not work on enum field

Tags: micronaut

I made a record that i want to use as dto object like this:

```
@Introspected()
@Requires(beans=MyEnum.class)//that was just a try
public record MyDtoRecord(String id, MyEnum enumField) {
}
```

and a Enum like this:

```
@Introspected()
public enum MyEnum {

  AVALUE("aText"),
  BVALUE("bText");

  public String text;

  MyEnum(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

I would expected to recieve my dto with the enum as property with the enum fields. Like this:

```
{id:"hello",enumField:{AVALUE:{text:"atext"}}}
//or like this:
{id:"hello",enumField:{value:"AVALUE", text:"atext"}}
```

but instead i only get the enum identifier:

```
{id:"hello",enumField:"AVALUE"}
```

I already tried to use custom annotations on fields of the enum with the includedAnnotations - Parameter of @Introspected
I also tried accessKind METHODE.

Nothing changed.

Is it not possible to get the fields of an enum field in a introspected class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the `text` field with `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue`.

Comment: Interesting. Only problem is now that i dont have an identifier anymore. But it was already really helpful. I didnt know Micronaut works with Jackson too.
Did I misunderstand the @Introspected annotation? Do I even need it to send data or is it just necessary when I want to retrieve data on my api?

Comment: "I didnt know Micronaut works with Jackson too." - It does. "Did I misunderstand the @Introspected annotation?" - If you thought it would change the structure of the generated JSON, yes.  `@Introspected` replaces some runtime reflection with compile time bean introspection. " Do I even need it to send data or is it just necessary when I want to retrieve data on my api?" - Strictly speaking, no, but it contributes a runtime performance improvement.

Comment: So I can use ```@Introspected```  to reduce memory consumption, but if want any special mapping I should use ```@JsonFormat``` and other Jackson annotations?

Comment: Yes, the performance improvements and the customization of the format and content of the generated JSON are separate but related concerns.